# How to create marquee in Android using only java code without xml

Tags: android

I need to create Marquee in Android  using only java code without using xml? Please provide me with resources to program in Android using only Java code without using xml.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Start from [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/custom-components.html) to learn how you can create a custom View. You can insert your View into a layout using both an XML or Java code. Doing it with Java code will be more complicated. This blog [post](http://mylifewithandroid.blogspot.com/2007/12/xml-and-programmatic-layout.html) has an example.

Answer (score 0):

Use the [`LinearLayout`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/LinearLayout.html) class. It is usually easy to translate an XML layout to Java code that will generate the same layout - the names of the XML elements are the same as the classes' names.

However, I would still recommend that you learn to use XML files for UI in Android, for the following reasons:

- Better separation of UI layout and application logic.
- The declarative syntax of XML is easier to use.
- Automatic adaptation to different screen sizes and resolutions - just place the various layout files in the folders they should go in.

Comment: Thanks for the help, But my application demands dynamic UI creation so Iam left with no option but to code in java. Is there any book out there which explains UI creation in Android with only Java ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use my code provide at git hub devender197/marqueeView. Or if you want to make marquee directly u can add following

step 1. Add it in your root build.gradle at the end of repositories:

```
allprojects {
    repositories {
        ...
        maven { url 'https://jitpack.io' }
    }
}Copy
```

Step 2. Add the dependency

```
dependencies {
        compile 'com.github.devender197:MarqueeView:0.0.1'
}
```